# jqgrid and fixed header

Tags: jquery, css, jqgrid

I have a fixed title bar but jqgrid element doesn't scroll correctly... When I scroll text, text goes behind title bar (correct), jqgrid not (wrong)

How can I do to resolve this problem?

Tranks in advance!
Roby

EDIT:
Screeshot: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BxGEE1yw1kGwLVdOVzdKRWlDcTA

The code is very simple:

```
<div id='divListVol' class='divList stat' > 
        <!-- Lista dei volontari -->
        <table id="listVol" class='stat'></table>
        <div id="pagerListVol" class='stat'></div>
 </div>

jQuery("#listVol").jqGrid({
            url: 'php/getVolontari.php?for=list',
            datatype: "json",
            contentType: "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1",
            loadonce:true,
            colNames:['Cod','Cognome', 'Nome','Modifica!'],
            colModel:[ {
                name:'id',
                index:'id',
                sortable: false,
                width: 10
            },{
                name:'cognome',
                index:'cognome',
                sortable: true,
                width: 35

            },{
                name:'nome',
                index:'nome',
                width: 35
            },{
                name:'modifica',
                index:'modifica',
                sortable: false,
                width: 20

            }],
            onSelectRow: function(rowid) { 
           $.ajax({
              url: "php/myRequest.php?for=info&id="+rowid,
              type:"GET",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(response) {.....},
              error: function(response) { ... }

            });


            },
            onCellSelect: function (rowid, iCol) {
                ...
            },
            rowNum:30,
            rowList:[10,20,30], 
            height: 'auto',
            width: 455,
            ignoreCase: true,
            autowidth: true,
            pager: '#pagerListVol',
            sortname: 'cognome',
            viewrecords: true, 
            sortorder: "asc", 
            caption:"Lista Volontari",
            multiselect: false,
        });
        jQuery("#listVol").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerListVol',{refresh:true, search:true, add:false,edit:false,del:false});
```

Comment: Could you include your code / what you have tried please? :)

Comment: If possible, create a simplified version in http://jsfiddle.net. It will make it much easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, jqGrid is just a DOM element, and you should be able to resolve your problem by adjusting CSS properties such as `position: relative | fixed | absolute;`

You didn't seem to provide that much information so I can completely answer your question. Can you please be more specific by providing CSS of the container jqGrid is hosted in?

Thanks.